# foo(char*): call with hardcoded byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a function `foo` that takes a `char*`. I'd like to call that function with hardcoded `{0x00, 0xff}` *without* assigning it to variables first.

```cpp
// out of my control, uses char* as a byte array:
void foo(const char*){}

int main(void)
{
  // First assigning to unsigned char (unsigned necessary for 0xff)
  // then casting to char* and calling works:
  unsigned char x[2] = {0x00, 0xff};
  foo((char *)x);

  // foo({0x00, 0xff}); // err, cannot interpret the braces

  // Hint: const char
  foo((const char[]){0x00, 0x01}); // works (but not with 0xff)

  return 0;
}
```

Any hints?

Comment: Curly braces without type specifications (like what you did in line 7) is an initialization list, not an array. You can decay a c-style array into a pointer (so the call in line 8 works), you can't decay an initialization list into a pointer.

Comment: Also, suppose for a second that curly braces without type specification was a c-style array. Foo receives a pointer to a char that can be modified (=not const). But where is the array you passed? It is a temporary variable whos lifetime would end at the end of the call to foo. What happens when you modify it? Modifying it is weird and most likely wrong.
That is why you cant pass temporary variables to functions that receives non-const reference/pointer variables.

Comment: fwiw, `char` and `unsigned char` are two distinct types. `char` can be signed or unsigned

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yeah, but they can be cast to one another (and `signed char`) without loss of information. Perhaps `reinterpret_cast` or `static_cast` is more accurate?

Comment: `{0x00, 0xff}` doesnt have a type, it can be used when constructors are called or for initialization of an array, but `char*` is not an array, its just a pointer. You need to store the array somewhere

Comment: @shakedcohen Does the game change if `foo` takes a `const char*`? I could certainly make it so.

Comment: This is an XY problem. Why do you want to call `foo(char*)`? Couldn't this be a `std::span`? Why is it important to use `unsigned char` in one place, but `char` in another place? What justifies this type difference? Shouldn't you be using `std::byte`? What version of C++ is this specific too? Are you not working on a project where C-style arrays are discouraged? Why aren't you using `std::array`? Why use C-style casts instead of `reinterpret_cast`? Would either be okay and you're just trying to be concise? This question needs clarity.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer I don't think it is going to help in this case because a "naked" { 0x00, 0xff } is not an array. It is of a different type called an initializer list.

Comment: @shakedcohen I actually got something. See modified question.

Comment: @JanSchultke Thanks for the hints. I've clarified the question, hopefully this helps.

Comment: @shakedcohen "It is of a different type called an initializer list."  not really. `{ 0x00,0xff}` doesnt have a type

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai you are right that it doesn't have a type, you can initialize different types with this syntax. But if the compiler can't figure out wtf you are trying to initialize, it will default to an initializer list and the error will be accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably just use a string literal, nice and simple:

```
foo("\x00\xff");
```

In this case, the string literal has type `const char[3]`, which *decays* into a `const char*` - exactly what `foo()` is expecting.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is by creating an alias template for arrays:

```cpp
template <typename T>
using array = T[];

void foo(char*);

int main() {
    foo((char*) array<unsigned char>{0x00, 0xff}); 
}
```

Note that the C-style cast is performing array-to-pointer conversion, and also reinterpreting the `unsigned char*` as a `char*`. The same could be achieved using `reinterpret_cast` and `static_cast`, or using:

```cpp
// note: static_cast is necessary to avoid a narrowing conversion here,
//       assuming that char is signed
foo(array<char>{0x00, static_cast<char>(0xff)});
```

While this technically solves the issue, this isn't particularly elegant or idiomatic code. The "modern" variant would be `std::span<char>` and passing a `std::array`. Since you're limited, and `foo` always accepts a `char*` as a byte array, the next best one-liner would be:

```cpp
foo(reinterpret_cast<char*>(std::array<unsigned char>{0x00, 0xff}.data()));
```

This is more verbose than the first version. However, many people would find the `array` template trick surprising, and would be be arguing against its use in code review.

By the way, the code

> ```cpp
> foo((const char[]){0x00, 0x01});
> ```

makes use of compound literals, which is a GNU compiler extension that adds this C99 feature to C++.
I would advise against it due to the obvious portability issues.